# How can I merge multiple values in one cell in python

Tags: python, merge

I have two dataframes. I have to lookup at dataframe 2 and input corresponding values in dataframe 1 or make a new dataframe. How can I do it in python?

**Inputs:**

**Dataframe 1**:

> Value: 10, [20,30], 5

**Dataframe 2**:

> Value: 10, 20, 30, 5
> Letter: a, b, a, c

****Output should be like this****

**Dataframe 3**:

> Value: 10, [20,30], 5
> Letter: a, [b,a], c

[input 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpEmH.png)
[input 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6s56k.png)
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IngZX.png)

Comment: For reference: Markdown for links does not work on indented lines - you can't link stuff that's inside a code block, and the reference URLs also need to be unindented to be recognized.

Answer (score 0):

So you have one DataFrame column that can contain either a simple value or a list, and a second DataFrame that you want to use as a translations table.

I will assume that the column `Value` in `df2` only contain unique values.

A simple way is to explode `df1.Value` to have one single value in each cell, and reset the index to store the original index in a dataframe column to be able to later aggregate on it. Then you just merge with `df2` and aggregate on the saved original index:

```
df1.reset_index().explode('Value').merge(df2, how='left', on='Value'
                         ).groupby('index').agg(
    lambda x: x.iat[0] if len(x) == 1 else x.to_list())
```

it gives as expected:

```
          Value  Letter
index                  
0            10       a
1      [20, 30]  [b, a]
2             5       c
```